# Return html table in php function

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm new to PHP and I come from Objective-C. I need to create a plugin for WP that returns an HTML table where each row is populated by data from JSON. In essence, as an example, I need to replace `echo` with `return`:

```
$jsonurl = "http://xxxx/club/api/xxxx/category/";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
//print_r ($json_output);

echo "<table>";
foreach ( $json_output->result as $result )
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$result->id."</td><td>".$result->categoryKind."</td><td>".$result->ranking."</td>";
}
echo "</table>" ;
```

That works! I can see output as expected. But for showing table in WP through Shortcode, I need `return` and no `echo`. So how can I replace the `echo` with `return`?

I tried:

```
function foobar_func(){

    $html= "<table>";

    foreach ( $json_output->result as $result )
    {
        $html. = "<tr><td>".$result->id."</td><td>".$result->categoryKind."</td><td>".$result->ranking."</td>";
    }
    $html. = "</table>" ;

    return $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

without success.  Any help is welcome.

**UPDATE**: Same result (no work). I will exit crazy.

```
function foobar_func($json_output){

    $html= "<table>";
    foreach ( $json_output->result as $result )
    {
        $html. = "<tr><td>".$result->id."</td><td>".$result->categoryKond."</td>  <td>".$result->ranking."</td>";
    }
    $html. = "</table>" ;

    return $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Comment: `$json_output` is undefined in your function, therefore you're looping on a non-existent variable.

Comment: are passing `$json_output` var in to this func?

Comment: thank you Marco, can you be a bit more explanatory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating I found the way out. But honestly I can't understand why this code works. Thank you all for putting me on the right path.

Code:

```
function foobar_func($json_output){
    $jsonurl = "http://xxxx/club/api/xxx/category/";
    $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
    $json_output = json_decode($json);
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ( $json_output->result as $result )
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$result->id."</td><td>".$result->categoryKind."</td><td>".$result->ranking."</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>" ;
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable scope is your problem here. `$json_output` isn't accessible within the function.

Change to the following:

```
function foobar_func(){

global $json_output;

$html= "<table>";
```

Alternatively to calling it as a global variable, you can pass it within the function call.

```
function foobar_func($json_output){
```

And then when you call the function, use `foobar_func($json_output)`

Answer (score 0):

please try ob_start() method i think it useful to you.
        http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

```
<?php
function callback($buffer)
{
  // replace all the apples with oranges
  return (str_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still facing an issue with this:

1. Cut everything inside of your function and just return any string:

   ```
   function foobar_func(){
       return "Hi";
   }
   add_shortcode('foobar', 'foobar_func');
   ```
2. Publish your page
3. Go back to your *functions.php*
4. Delete *return "Hi";*
5. Paste your full code inside the function

The page will take the output from your code without the need to publish it again.